# Sequencing error with channels in IBM MQ v9.1

Tags: ibm-mq

everytime queue manager is getting started in any of cluster nodes RCVR channel is getting reset to seqnum(1) . SDR channel is going to retrying state due to sequence mismatch and manually channels are required to be reset. Is there any other work around to avoid manually resetting of seq number?

RCVR end channel def :

```
   CHANNEL(XXXXX)                          CHLTYPE(RCVR)
   ALTDATE(2021-02-10)                     ALTTIME(16.19.35)
   BATCHSZ(50)                             CERTLABL( )
   COMPHDR(NONE)                           COMPMSG(NONE)
   DESCR( )                                HBINT(300)
   KAINT(AUTO)                             MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MCAUSER( )                              MONCHL(QMGR)
   MRDATA( )                               MREXIT( )
   MRRTY(10)                               MRTMR(1000)
   MSGDATA( )                              MSGEXIT( )
   NPMSPEED(FAST)                          PUTAUT(DEF)
   RCVDATA( )                              RCVEXIT( )
   RESETSEQ(NO)                            SCYDATA( )
   SCYEXIT( )                              SENDDATA( )
   SENDEXIT( )                             SEQWRAP(999999999)
   SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
   SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256)
   SSLPEER( )                              STATCHL(QMGR)
   TRPTYPE(TCP)                            USEDLQ(YES)
```

Comment: Can you show `DIS CHS(XXXXX) CURSEQNO LSTSEQNO SAVED`?  Can you confirm you RCVR did not have a MCAUSER set?

Comment: Thank you @JoshMc, please find below details :

Comment: CHANNEL(xxxx)            CHLTYPE(RCVR)
   CONNAME(xxxx)                     SAVED
   CURSEQNO(25)                            LSTSEQNO(25)
   STATUS(STOPPED)

   CHANNEL(xxxx)            CHLTYPE(RCVR)
   MCAUSER( )                                                   
  CHANNEL(xxxxx)            CHLTYPE(SDR)
   CONNAME(xxxx)                     SAVED
   CURSEQNO(25)                            LSTSEQNO(25)
   STATUS(STOPPED)                         XMITQ(xxxx)

Comment: Do you know why your sequence numbers are mismatched? Are you for example, deleting the RCVR channel? Or perhaps deleting the whole queue manager at the RCVR end?

Comment: You mention "cluster nodes". Can you elaborate further on the type of "clustering" in use and how the queue manager state is replicated/shared?

Comment: @MoragHughson, We are using SUNW.gds cluster where QM will be available only on a single node, if that node goes down the other node will come up along with QM. Sequence number at RCVR end is always getting reset to 1 automatically after the queue manager is getting restarted. Its value is not getting synchronized with SDR end.

Comment: also, what I have noticed from channel file is that channel is getting updated everytime queue manger is getting restarted .                                                                                            -rw-rw----   1 mqm      mqm        10624 May  7 16:08   xxxxxx                                       But the channel was created on below date :                                     CHANNEL(xxxxxxx)            CHLTYPE(RCVR)
   ALTDATE(2021-02-10)                     ALTTIME(16.19.35)

Comment: I'm not familiar with SUNW.gds cluster - I assume you are doing something like this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19050-01/sun.cluster31/817-1713/6mhe5bcii/index.html and sharing the MQ logs and MQ data directory? Can you show us exactly the directories from your queue manager that are being shared?

Comment: Please update your question with details so they can be formatted fixed don't with line breaks.